# How to write calculate recursively the square root of an int (in Assembly) given C code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to pass in a vlue x into a code block of assembly that recursively calculates the the square root of an int using this logic shown in C below

```
 int r_sqrt(int x){
    if(x < 0)
        return -1;
    if (x < 2)
        return x;
   /* recursive call */
    int small_cand = r_sqrt(x >> 2) << 1;
    int large_cand = small_cand + 1;
    if (large_cand * large_cand > x)
        return small_cand;
    else
        return large_cand;
 }
```

Here is what I have tried to far where the value to be sqrted is in %edi

```
r_sqrt:
    # Base case checks
    push %rdi           # Save original x
    cmp $0, %edi
    jl .negative_value  # If x < 0, it's an error, return -1
    cmp $2, %edi
    jb .return_x        # If x < 2, the square root is x itself

    # Prepare for the recursive call
    mov %edi, %r10d     # Save original x in r10d
    sar $2, %edi        # x = x >> 2 (divide by 4)
    call r_sqrt         # Recursive call r_sqrt(x >> 2)

    # After recursive call, eax contains r_sqrt(x >> 2)
    # Calculate small_cand based on the result
    shl $1, %eax        # eax = eax << 1 (small_cand)
    mov %eax, %ecx      # Store small_cand in ecx for later

    # Calculate large_cand based on small_cand
    pop %rdi            # Restore original x
    inc %eax            # Increment small_cand to get large_cand
    push %rax           # Save large_cand
    mov %eax, %edx      # Store large_cand in edx
    imul %eax, %eax     # large_cand * large_cand
    cmp %eax, %edi      # Compare large_cand^2 with the original
    jg .small_cand      # If large_cand^2 > x, use small_cand

    # Else, return large_cand
    pop %rax            # Restore large_cand
    ret

.small_cand:
    mov %ecx, %eax      # Move small_cand to eax
    pop %rax            # Pop and discard the previously saved large_cand value
    ret

.return_x:
    pop %rax            # Restore original x
    mov %edi, %eax      # Move x to eax for return
    ret

.negative_value:
    pop %rax            # Restore original x
    mov $-1, %eax       # Return -1 for negative inputs
    ret
```

The results I am getting are vs what they should equal are:
sqrt(0) = 0 should be -> 0

sqrt(2) = 1 should be -> 1

sqrt(3) = 3 should be -> 2

sqrt(4) = 7 should be -> 6

Comment: The square root of 4 should be 6? I seem to have missed something here...

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through the instruction in both C and ASM codes and see where the intermediate results start to deviate.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/dErMEx9ab shows `r_sqrt(4) = 2` with your C code, as expected.  Maybe you meant `r_sqrt(7)` should be `4` or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, figured it out already that `edi` is a part of `rdi`, thanks. The only x86 assembly I practically worked with had 16 bit registers :D

Comment: In `.small_cand:`, the last instruction is `pop %rax` which pops into the return value register.  That's not "discarding".  Either pop first, pop into RCX or RDX, or use `add $8, %rsp`.  Use a debugger to check for other bugs in any other test-cases that mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to solve the question

```
r_sqrt:

# Base case checks
testl %edi, %edi         # If x < 0, it's an error, return -1
jl .negative_value
cmpl $2, %edi         # If x < 2, the square root is x itself
jl .return_x

# Save caller-saved registers
pushq %rdi            # Save original value of x

# Prepare for the recursive call
shrl $2, %edi         # x = x >> 2 (divide by 4) for recursive call
call r_sqrt          # Recursive call r_sqrt(x >> 2)

popq %rdi
# Calculate candidates for the square root
shll $1, %eax         # Double the result for small candidate

# Increment eax to get the large candidate
leal 1(%eax),%edx
movl %edx, %ecx       # Move small candidate to ebx



# Check if large candidate is the correct square root
imull %edx, %edx      # Square of large candidate
cmpl %edi, %edx       # Compare original x with square of large candidate
jg .large_cand     
movl %ecx, %eax
ret

.large_cand:
ret

.return_x:
# For x < 2, return x itself
mov %edi, %eax       # Move x to eax for return
ret

.negative_value:
# Return -1 for negative inputs
mov $-1, %eax        # Set return value to -1
ret
```